# How to initialise an empty Numpy array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In Python we can initialise an array with `[[]]`. But how to initialise a Numpy array without using `numpy.zeros`, `numpy.ones` & `numpy.empty` ? I don't want to use these functions because it fills in my Numpy array.

Comment: note that numpy arrays are not dynamically growing arrays. So in most cases initializing a completely empty array makes no sense.

Comment: `numpy.empty` doesn't fill your array, it just allocates some memory space of appropriate size and keeps that memory "as is".

Answer (score 1):

All the lack of sense in your question aside (Numpy arrays are statically sized on creation),

```
numpy.ndarray((dim1,dim2,...))
```

will create a dim1 x dim2 (x dimN) array and skip initialization.